# Azure Graph API - Unable to retrieve SSPR data using various $Filter statements

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Customer is attempting to retrieve just SSPR data using the following Azure Graph API call within script:

$url = "https://graph.windows.net/$tenantdomain/activities/audit?api-version=beta&$filter='category eq SSPR'"

Appears to bring back ALL the audit data and not just the category of "SSPR".  Also, if you attempt to filter the data further with an "AND" statement within the $Filter, it does not work.

$url = "https://graph.windows.net/$tenantdomain/activities/audit?api-version=beta&$filter=category EQ ‘SSPR’ and (activity EQ ‘User registered for self-service password reset')"

Still end up with all the Audit data and not just the filtered data.  Can you please assist with a valid query to return strictly  SSPR Audit data that has an indication of "User registered for self-service-password-rest" if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Azure Active Directory audit API](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory/active-directory-reporting-api-audit-reference.md#category), it supports filter category fields

**example:**

```
$filter=category eq 'SSPR'
```

**Url:**

```
https://graph.windows.net/{domainname}/activities/audit?api-version=beta&$filter=category eq 'SSPR'
```

I also test it with postman, it works correctly on my side.

[image]